# How to make Nvidia GeForce card unaware it's in VM?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v, nvidia-geforce

My configuration:

- Hypervizor - Hyper-V
- Host OS: Windows Server 2019
- Guest OS: Windows 10
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060

I succeeded to pass-through the GPU to the VM as described [here](https://www.withinrafael.com/2020/06/06/how-to-get-consumer-gpus-working-in-hyperv-virtual-machines/). But, I get error with ***Code 43*** when I install Nvidia driver in VM. The reason for that is Nvidia driver checks whether the GeForce card is used within the VM and disables it. That's why the author in [this](https://www.withinrafael.com/2020/06/06/how-to-get-consumer-gpus-working-in-hyperv-virtual-machines/) forum created a script that patches the driver.

But, the script fixes the driver for **NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980** card. It replaces specific bytes in `nvlddmkm.sys` file. But, the author doesn't explain how he found out what bytes should be replaced. My understanding that those bytes correspond to hypervisor CPUID.

Does anyone know what bytes should I look and replace so I could do the same for the driver for my GPU?

Comment: NVIDIA has allowed virtualisation for "consumer-grade" GPU a couple of days ago. Officially it relates to Linux hosts and Windows guests. But you may try to install the newest beta driver in guest Windows and check. https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5173/~/geforce-gpu-passthrough-for-windows-virtual-machine-%28beta%29

Comment: @batistuta09 - You should submit that as an answer and quote the article

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA has allowed virtualisation for "consumer-grade" GPU a couple of days ago. Officially it relates to Linux hosts and Windows guests. But you may try to install the newest beta driver in guest Windows and check.

[https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5173/~/geforce-gpu-passthrough-for-windows-virtual-machine-%28beta%29](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5173/%7E/geforce-gpu-passthrough-for-windows-virtual-machine-%28beta%29)

Comment: Yes, I tried the 465.89 driver. The driver gets installed, but when I look in Device Manager, the adapter (Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060) still has little yellow triangle. If I open Properties, it still shows ***Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)***